# VSCode doesn't open Files imported with absolute PATH

Tags: linux, path, visual-studio-code

I have a React Application. I am importing some components, and I want to click ALT+File name in the import in order to navigate to it.(Linux Ubuntu). `Mapped it to Alt instead of CTRL`.

In files with relative paths like so:

```
import ComponentRelative from '../../somewhere';
```

It works just fine. I Alt+Click on the `ComponentRelataive` and it takes me to the that file.

Now on absolute paths, that doesn't work. I am assuming it is because VSCode doesn't start in the root of my system. I could be wrong though. To give an example:

```
import ComponentAbsolute from 'common/components/ComponentAbsolute';
```

This doesn't work. I tried searching for something in VSCode docs, but haven't found anything similar in the settings. Has anyone seen this problem, and know how to solve it. Thanks!!

Comment: This doesn't look like an absolute path to me? Usually it would look like `/usr/include/` or etc.?